# Specifying Correct VS 2012 VC/MFC Runtime Using Manifest Files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, manifest, msvcrt

We've recently converted a large MFC-based suite of projects from Visual Studio 2005/2008 to Visual Studio 2012 (Update 5).  Our projects previously used a set of configuration-specific manifest files, embedded as resources, to specify the exact version of the side-by-side (SxS) assemblies to load.  As an example, below here is a snippet from one of our old manifest files for the VC90 runtime:

```
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.30729.1" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
```

Previously, I could associate the identity above with a folder at C:\Windows\WinSxS.  An example would be the folder "x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_e163563597edeada" which contains the correct binaries.

As you can see, the folder name contains all the information necessary to populate the assemblyIdentity node's attributes.  Unfortunately, [this](http://www.tmurgent.com/appv/index.php/en/component/content/article?id=156:visual-studio-runtime-versions) (outdated) article confirms my findings that Microsoft no longer stores VC2010+ SxS files in this manner.  **I want to tell our projects to run against the latest Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (installer v11.0.61030.0).  How do I locate the correct name/version/publicKeyToken information for these binaries?**  I could not find an MSDN listing or similar.

Note that I've been using sxstrace.exe / Dependency Walker and the like to investigate this issue.  I can confirm the manifest files are being appropriately embedded in our executables; the issue is only the manifest files are specified incorrectly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235265(v=vs.110).aspx). As I remember correctly by default your application will be linked to libs as in your Windows SDK. And to make project use default libs just delete info about them inside your project file or recreate project with default settings.